# Which version of DotNetOpenAuth does Stack Overflow use?

Tags: discussion, authentication, dotnetopenauth

Which version of DotNetOpenAuth does Stack Overflow use?
I wonder because the latest CTP version of DotNetOpenAuth seems to have dropped support for Facebook. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365245/updated-version-of-facebook-client-for-dotnetopenauth/6372707#6372707).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're running against latest 3.4.7, not the CTP.

Our Facebook OAuth 2.0 support is homegrown, not using dotNetOpenAuth at all.

Comment: Ah right - thanks for the info.